# Accessing JavaScript methods inside nested Polymer custom elements

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I am trying to access the Javascript methods contained within a Polymer custom element, `<general-element>`. This element contains functions to open and close a panel.

This general element is used within a more specific element, e.g: `<specific-element></specific-element>`. The specific element contains the general element and adds attributes to it, i.e: a panel title etc.

However, when using `<specific-element>` within a page, I am unable to call any of the open/close methods from  through it. Am I approaching this from the wrong way, and is there a way to do this?

**Edit: Code Examples**

Have removed some Polymer code - examples just to show how the elements work together

General Element:

```
<dom-module id="general-element">
    <template>
        // Code to define a slide-in panel
    </template>

    <script>
        _openPanel: function() {
            //Apply class to make panel visible
        },
        _closePanel: function() {
            // Apply class to hide panel
        }
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Specific Element:

```
<dom-module id="specific-element">
    <template>
        <general-element title="Administration Panel" >
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </general-element>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

Usage:

```
<dom-module id="admin-page">
    <template>
        <button on-click="openPanel"></button>
        <specific-element></specific-element>
    </template>

    <script>
        openPanel: function() {
            // Trying to call general-element _openPanel method
        }
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

What I am trying to do here is call the openPanel behaviour   as already described in general-element. This is because the panel will be used in multiple places, so it doesn't make sense to keep implementing open/close methods for specific panels as they will work in the same way.

Comment: Some actual code would be nice that shows how the elements are related.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Have added code examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
openPanel: function() {
  // Trying to call general-element _openPanel method
  $$('specific-element').$$('general-element')._openPanel();   
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: About time. I have been searching and searching. Thanks.